# Why should i use my hosting dns servers?

Tags: dns, hosting

I recently adquried a new domain name with Godaddy. And rented a Dedicated server with another provider (OVH).

I´ve found that Godaddy suggests to change the authoritative nameservers of the domain to my hosting dns servers, but... Why?
 (http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/664/setting-nameservers-for-your-domain-names)s

Godaddy provided dns servers are actually working in resolving the domain to the hosting ip perfectly, by just editing in godaddy the zone file and changed the @ host to my new ip.

Is there any benefit in doing what godaddy suggests?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is usually more valuable with shared plans via a control panel.  If you change your name servers to theirs, then you can manage your zone in the same interface as you do your hosting setup.  This doesn't fly in a dedicated environment, but it is probably a default recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

When selecting secondary servers, attention should be given to the various likely failure modes.  Servers should be placed so that it is likely that at least one server will be available to all significant parts of the Internet, for any likely failure.

Consequently, placing all servers at the local site, while easy to arrange, and easy to manage, is not a good policy.  Should a single link fail, or there be a site, or perhaps even building, or room, power failure, such a configuration can lead to all servers being disconnected from the Internet.

Secondary servers must be placed at both topologically and geographically dispersed locations on the Internet, to minimise the likelihood of a single failure disabling all of them.

That is, secondary servers should be at geographically distant locations, so it is unlikely that events like power loss, etc, will disrupt all of them simultaneously.  They should also be connected to the net via quite diverse paths.  This means that the failure of any one link, or of routing within some segment of the network (such as a service provider) will not make all of the servers unreachable.

It's a best practice to split primary and secondary DNS servers to independent hosting providers to avoid be in the situation like [this](http://www.godaddy.com/news/article/go-daddy-site-outage-investigation-completed.aspx)

You can get more info at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2182

Answer (score 0):

Usually your hosting company wants to control DNS so that you have a single point of configuration. It really depends on what you're buying from your hosting company and what you expect out of it.

If the configuration you have works, just keep using that for now. You may find that's not the case some day, but you can worry about any problems then.

Answer (score 0):

Technical benefits for you:

1. One network location - if godaddy network fails, then OVH web server will become unavailable for resolvers. If OVH network fails - web server is unavailable anyway.
2. Service provider might have some additional internal tools for analysis of attacks which may work better if both DNS and web servers are under control of the same system.

You can use DNS servers from both providers simultaneously to avoid single point of failure of network and DNS, but in all these three cases - It doesn't look critical from my point of view.